# Ability to hide posts from communities I don't care about

Tags: feature-request

I like the “Hot Network Questions” feature of the site. But, there are entire communities that are of no interest to me whatsoever. It's just an irritation, but it happens a lot. The worst are ones that seem to be interesting questions, but then have to do with imaginary worlds of some sort. I would like to be able to hide questions from certain communities.